# C#: Does function return type override object casting?

Tags: c#, inheritance, unity-game-engine, interface, polymorphism

I am unsure what technical term to use to describe this scenario, so here is my case.

> **Context:**

I am designing an Item system for a game. Currently, there exists a BaseGameItem class that contains basic parameters such as Id, name, icon etc...
So far there exists another class derived from it, called the PickupItem which implements IPickupItem. All seems fine until I try to initialize these objects via an Item Spawner.

> The key idea is that, there exists a persistent database that the
>   spawner refers to when initializing the objects, it then proceeds to
>   spit out the fully initialized object as shown:

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Initialize Game Item:
    /// Given an Item ID, constructs a BaseGameItem object and returns it to instigator.
    /// Refers to ItemInfoTable to initialize object parameters.
    /// </summary>
    /// Paramater - Int ID: The provided Item ID
    /// Parameter - out BaseGameItem Item: The constructed object returned to the instigator.
    public static void InitializeGameItem(int id, out BaseGameItem item)
    {
        FItemInfoData itemInfoData = ItemTable.Find(x => x.ItemID == id);

        if(itemInfoData.ItemID != id)
        {
            itemInfoData = ItemTable[0];
        }

        // Check if item is a Pickup. If so, then item is returned as a PickupPlaceable.
        // Otherwise, initialize to BaseGameItem.
        item = itemInfoData.IsPickupItem ? new PickupPlaceable() : new BaseGameItem();

        item.SetItemName(itemInfoData.ItemName);
        item.SetItemDescription(itemInfoData.ItemDescription);
        item.SetItemIcon(itemInfoData.ItemIcon);
        item.SetItemMesh(itemInfoData.ItemMesh);
    }
```

My questions are as follows:

1. In order to know which class I should return or what interface the item is implementing, I included a Boolean in the database that checks if it is a Pickup object. Is this a wise decision? If you can direct me to an article or a design pattern used in such scenario, I would be very grateful.
2. **My main concern however is the return type. I am using the out keyword and am outputting a BaseGameItem object. However, in my ternary condition, I can initialize it to the derived Pickup item. Will the function output cast it down to a BaseGameItem, and hence will lose all Pickup functionalities? Or does it interpret any derived class as a valid return type?**
3. If the object is returned as BaseGameItem regardless, shouldn't the receiver be aware that they have to cast it to a derived class? How does one remedy the problem, do I simply return a Boolean indicating it's a Pickup within the initialize function so that the receiver will know when to cast appropriately?

Comment: What happened when you actually ran the code?

Comment: I think this question is better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: May be worth noting that you don't lose functionality on an object when you cast; you merely lose access to functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. > In order to know which class I should return or what interface the item is implementing, I included a Boolean in the database that checks if it is a Pickup object. Is this a wise decision? If you can direct me to an article or a design pattern used in such scenario, I would be very grateful.

You are on the right track with [factory method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern):

2. > My main concern however is the return type. I am using the out keyword and am outputting a BaseGameItem object. However, in my ternary condition, I can initialize it to the derived Pickup item. Will the function output cast it down to a BaseGameItem, and hence will lose all Pickup functionalities? Or does it interpret any derived class as a valid return type?

The return type will not lose functionalities from upcasting:

> Base classes may define and implement virtual methods, and derived classes can override them, which means they provide their own definition and implementation. At run-time, when client code calls the method, the CLR looks up the run-time type of the object, and invokes that override of the virtual method. Thus in your source code you can call a method on a base class, and cause a derived class's version of the method to be executed.

-- [Polymorphism (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism)

3. > If the object is returned as BaseGameItem regardless, shouldn't the receiver be aware that they have to cast it to a derived class? How does one remedy the problem, do I simply return a Boolean indicating it's a Pickup within the initialize function so that the receiver will know when to cast appropriately?

No, "Thus in your source code you can call a method on a base class, and cause a derived class's version of the method to be executed." However, when you need a particular functionality from the derived class, like `PickupPlaceable.Pickup()`, you will have to downcast it first

EDIT:

> The problem becomes, how does the receiver know if the base item should be cast.

You can always check if an item can be picked up using the `is` or `as` keyword:

```
if (item is PickupPlaceable)
{
     var loot = (PickupPlaceable)item;
     loot.Pickup();
}

var loot = item as PickupPlaceable;
if (loot != null)
{
     loot.Pickup();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate response! Regarding the last two points, I am getting the impression that my design does not make use of that approach, correct? Because the BaseGameItem class simply does not implement the Pickup interface to begin with. Is it ok to "pollute" the parent class with the virtual methods even though they are not to be used by the parent? Do note that for the sake of exercise,I intend to derive another class called "Interactable" which also should not have Pickup functionalities.

Comment: @AAS.N Of course it is ok to use abstract methods, but in your case I think that you should use interfaces instead, for example you could have Pickeable interface with pick method, then every item you want to be pickable will implement that interface, same goes for Interactable.

Comment: @FilipRistic Yep, that is exactly how I initially designed it. The issue stems from the fact that the Pickup class is a child of the BaseGameItem class. Only the Pickup class implements IPickup because the base class can be the parent of objects not meant to be picked up. So whenever the item spawner tries to initialize a game item, it has to output a BaseGameItem object as shown in the code above. Then the class receiving the object must cast it to the specific child that implements a desired functionality. The problem becomes, how does the receiver know if the base item should be cast.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 Sorry if I sound repetitive, but the spawner returns a BaseGameItem instance. Wouldn't the "is" keyword always return true since Pickup is a child class of BaseGameItem? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is

 I only want to it to return true if the InitializeGameItem function initialized item as a new PickupPlaceable and not a BaseGameItem.

Comment: a `BaseGameItem` isn't necessarily a `Pickup`, but a `Pickup` is always a `BaseGameItem`. Assuming `Pickup` derives from `BaseGameItem`.